# How to let standard user run an application without administrator previleges

Tags: windows-7

I want to give my younger brother access to the games on my Windows 7 PC while using a standard user. But on startup, each program requests the admin password which my brother obviously shouldn't get (with an admin user I had 3 trojans and 9 malware programs on my computer within 2 weeks).

What are the reasons Windows asks for the admin password for a game? Why should the game need administrator rights?

Comment: A program shouldn't ask for Administrator permissions unless it needs it.  This means you have to determine which permissions these applications actually require and grant them to the `User`group

Comment: Ditto. Are you downloading these games from someplace like Russia or China? I ask because they might be malware themselves. Or are you saying that you want your brother to be able to download new games and install them? (Still, there ought to be a “this-user-only” installation option that doesn’t require privileges.)

Comment: My brother shouldn't be able to install programms but open any programm which is installed. The games are installed via Steam and are saved on a different partition. Maybe steam remembers the place where it stored the game data and thus asks for admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe sometimes a program update may trigger a need for admin privileges. I want to say Steam has done this to me in the past, but I'm not certain.

If your brother isn't terribly clever, you could always replace the game shortcuts with batch scripts that use [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) to start the game. Downside is that your password would be in plain text, and if he opens up the batch script he will be able to log in to your account anyway.

[RunasSpc](http://www.robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html) might do the trick for you if he does have some wits about him. You'll create and encrypted file to open the program under your (or any) admin user. Something like this:

[image]

Then create a shortcut to launch the game from his Desktop as with a path as follows:

`c:\path_to_runasspc\runasspc.exe /cryptfile:"C:\Users\brother\somegame.spc"`

Now he can launch only the games that you choose under your profile, from his profile.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option at [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966). Quick synopsis here, but read the link for full details:

1. Use Task Scheduler to create a task.

   1. Enable "Run with highest privileges"
   2. Enable "Allow task to be run on demand" or the equivalent option.
2. Create a shortcut on the desktop that points to:

   `C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "FolderName\ScheduledTaskName"`

   1. Don't forget to change the icon to the regular application's icon!

Comment: I think this will need to be run as different user? Easy option though.

Comment: You should probably set it to "run as specific user" and specify your admin user with the password. The Task Scheduler stores the password so that it cannot be retrieved by the user.

Answer (score 1):

If a program is asking for administrative privelages (either through an embedded or external assembly manifest), you can override the elevation request, and force the application to run as a standard user.

For example, the program [**Game Cam**](http://xpress.planetgamecam.com/) insists that it be run as an administrator. It contains an embedded assembly manifest that contains the

```
runas="requireAdministrator"
```

entry. You can override this requirement; returning it to the default *"as invoker"*. The way to do that is to add a compability entry to the Windows registry:

```
HKCU\Softare\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags
   D:\Programs\Game Cam V2\GameCamV2.exe = RUNASINVOKER
```

This overrides the request by the application to run as an administrator, and instead forces the application to run as a standard user.

The application might not handle running as a standard user. Most software developers are lazy, and don't bother to test their applications. So the application might crash and burn horribly.

But at least it is running as a standard user.