# Turning On Admin Privledges For Certain Programs on XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

So I own an irritatingly old computer, Windows XP. We recently downloaded a game, League of Legends, and discovered it needed Administrative privileges to run and start up. The computers administrator is willing to work with me on this, but isn't sure how to fix the issues either- that being, **is is possible to make it so the program does not require the administrator to log in every time, even when the game is launched on another computer account? If so, how would would one go about do so?**
I understand XP is no longer supported and the fact my system is...old. Therefor, it either is or is not possible. It may just be that I'm out of luck until I/We can afford an upgrade.
I've been trying to read up on this specific issue but have not been able to really find an exact answer to my specific issue.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: No; it's not possible to modify the program so it does not need administrator permission

Comment: See [How to let standard user run an application without administrator privileges](http://superuser.com/q/778991/354511). It’s about Windows 7, and it’s not clear whether it was ever really resolved, but it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following as administrator.  Go to "C:\Program Files" and right click on the game folder ("League of Legends" or whatever the folder name is).  Select "Properties" then click the "Security" tab.  Add the user accounts that you want to be able run the game.  Then select each user you added and click "Allow" for "Modify".  Click apply then click on "Advanced".  I'm on Windows 8.1 so I don't remember the exact wording but there should be a checkbox that says "Replace all child object permissions...".  Check that option and hit apply.  This should give the users the rights needed to play the game.